# htacces if else index or admin

Tags: php, .htaccess, if-statement

I have the following htacces.

Is it possible to do an if/elseif in a htacces.

Example:
if http://url.nl/rs/ 
elseif http://url.nl/rs/admin/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . rs/index.php [L]
RewriteRule . rs/admin/index.php [L]
```

Comment: No idea what that if/elseif description means, if `http://url.nl/rs/` then what? What's supposed to happen if that condition is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url\.nl/rs$ [NC]
RewriteRule . rs/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url\.nl/rs/admin$ [NC]
RewriteRule . rs/admin/index.php [L]
```

Comment: the `%{HTTP_HOST}` doesn't have any path info, it's essentially the `Host: ` request header, which contains only a hostname

Comment: Must be something else other than apache's mod_rewrite, because the `%{HTTP_HOST}` var will never have a `/rs` in it, thus making both of those conditions always fail